# Python2.6 SCTP send and recieve hex values through sctp sockets

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, sctp

I am trying to do sctp programming using **Python2.6** and **pysctp** package. I was able to capture the message from the server but was not able to extract the hex dump of the received message from sctp socket. And how to send my **responseHex** as response using the same socket to the connected server.

Assume my server is independent of this client and it continuously trying to connect with the 192.168.10.13 address.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket
import pysctp
import pysctp.sctp as sctp

MAXRECVBUFFERSIZE = 2048
bindingIp  = "192.168.10.13"
socketPort = 112233;
socket     = sctp.sctpsocket_tcp(socket.AF_INET);

responseHex =[0xd0, 0x36, 0x02, 0x5a, 0x00, 0x51, 0x03, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x11];

socket.events.clear();
socket.bind((bindingIp, socketPort));
socket.listen(3);

client, addr = socket.accept();
buffer = client.recv(MAXRECVBUFFERSIZE);
print buffer   // This prints binary dump on the terminal
// And I want to send hexResponse variable through the same socket

socket.close();
exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, remember not to put semicolons on the end of your statements. You don't need exit(0) at the end of the file either.

To get a hex dump, of "buffer", you can say: `print map(hex, buffer)`

To send your hex response, the easiest way would be to alter the definition of responseHex to look like this:

`responseHex = '\xd0\x36\x02\x5a\x00\x51\x03\x00\x15\x00\x08\x00\x11'`

Then it should be able to be passed to the client.send() function.